# react calendar timeline issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time, calendar, timeline

I am facing some issue in `react-calendar-timeline` . i create a calendar using this package:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar-timeline
```

my code:

```
    this.state = {

      items: [],
      groups: [],

  componentDidMount() {

    var self = this;     
      axios
        .get(
          `http://localhost/v1/appointments`
        )
        .then(function(res){
           ....

          const itemsArray = items;
          const groupsArray = groups;
          self.setState({
            groups: groupsArray,
            items: itemsArray,
          });

        });



}


        <Timeline
           groups={this.state.groups}
           items={this.state.items}
          defaultTimeStart={moment().subtract(1, 'hour')}
          defaultTimeEnd={moment().add(3, 'hour').add(30, "minute")}
        />
```

[image]    };

I want to `current date vertical lines` on calendar

expected output

[image]

What should i do? anyone tell me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom TimelineMarkers

```
import Timeline, {
  TimelineMarkers,
  CustomMarker,
  TodayMarker,
  CursorMarker
} from 'react-calendar-timeline'

const today = new Date()

<Timeline>
  <TimelineMarkers>
    <TodayMarker />
    <CustomMarker date={today} />
    <CustomMarker date={tomorrow}>
      {/* custom renderer for this marker */}
      {({ styles, date }) => {
        const customStyles = {
          ...styles,
          backgroundColor: 'deeppink',
          width: '4px'
        }
        return <div style={customStyles} onClick={someCustomHandler} />
      }}
    </CustomMarker>
    <CursorMarker />
  </TimelineMarkers>
</Timeline>
```